# Google Maps não carrega corretamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps

Meu site está com problemas de exibição em uma mapa (Google Maps) quando acessado pela url principal: http://www.localizaip.com/

porém exibe o mesmo mapa corretamente quando acessado por esta outra URL: http://www.localizaip.com/en/

Se eu acesso o site por esta outra url http://www.localizaip.com/es/
também dá erro no mapa.

Alguém saberia dizer o que pode estar causando isso?

O código html do mapa é criado dinâmicamente dentro da seguinte div `<div id="map-canvas" style="min-height:248px; width:100%;"></div>`, e verifiquei que esta div encontra-se presente em ambas as páginas que citei.

As funções que deveriam criar o mapa dinamicamente são:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>

<script>
var mapMarker = "http://www.localizaip.com/site/images/geo_icon.png";
var latLngHome = new google.maps.LatLng("99,9999999","99,9999999");
var infoHome = '<div id="content">'+'<div id="siteNotice">'+'</div>'+'<h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Localização</h4>'+'<div id="bodyContent">'+'<p>Rua Tal<br/>Bairro, Cidade<br/>Estado - Brazil</p>'+'</div>'+'</div>';  

function initialize(myLatlng,infoWindowString) {

    if($('#map-canvas').length > 0){

          //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("","");
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlng
          }
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

          // Image Marker
          var image = mapMarker;
          var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: 'Localização'                
          });

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: infoWindowString
          });


        google.maps.event.addListener(beachMarker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,beachMarker);
        });

    }

}

var $ = jQuery.noConflict($);
$(document).ready(function(){    
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(latLngHome,infoHome));
});
</script>
```

Porém por algum motivo não está funcionando..

> Obs.: Estes erros começaram à aparecer depois que instalei um sistema de tradução em PHP no site (php-gettext), porém com a implementação deste sistema, não foram feitas alterações de javascript, e isso que achei mais estranho, pois não entendo como um sistema de PHP poderia afetar a funcionalidade do mapa que é criado usando javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo que meu problema estava relacionado aos scripts PHP de implementação de idioma (php-gettext).

Abaixo o código de como resolvi:

```
<?php

putenv('LANGUAGE=' . $locale);
putenv('LANG=' . $locale);
//putenv('LC_ALL=' . $locale); //Desabilitei esta linha 
putenv('LC_MESSAGES=' . $locale);

setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $locale);
//setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale); //Desabilitei esta linha

?>
```

Creio que de alguma forma a configuração de idioma estava afetando a exibição do Google Maps.
Porém desabilitando apenas duas linhas do script acima consegui resolver o problema, sem afetar a funcionalidade do sistema de traduções.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite.
Na página que está funcionando encontrei no código, a div que exibe o mapa:

Já nas páginas que estão apresentando o erro, não encontrei está parte no código. Já verificou se está correto? Se não está faltando a div onde é exibido o mapa nestas páginas com erro?

Comment: use os comentários quando tiver pontuação suficiente para esse tipo de pergunta, a sessão resposta é apenas para respostas que podem resolver o problema

Comment: Olá @Wesley! Verifiquei nas páginas e constatei que a div `<div id="map-canvas" style="min-height:248px; width:100%;"></div>` responsável por exibir o mapa está em ambas. De qualquer forma obrigado pela resposta.